# Unable to install NPM packages for project in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I will preface by saying I am a complete beginner at coding, and I signed up for the free trial of Pluralsight. I have spent the last four hours trying to get the very first project set up, as I have a mac and very few of the commands recommended by Pluralsight work on this computer. The project, cloned from git, is called web-dev-starter. Currently, I am trying to connect the Node packages needed for the project using the command

```
web-dev-starter> npm install
```

This returns
`zsh: command not found: web-dev-starter`

I have tried a lot of things and nothing works. Many thanks to whoever can help, I really want to learn to code and am considering buying a windows computer because trying to learn on a mac has been a nightmare! Thanks!

Comment: `web-dev-starter>` shouldn't be part of the command. Try only typing `npm install`, and make sure that the current directory (run `pwd` to check) is the correct location

Answer (score 2):

`web-dev-starter>` means the current directory from the file that you just clone. and after you are in that directory you just need to do `npm install`